# React Context does not work in Netlify. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, multilingual, react-context, use-context

I am having this issue every time I deploy my react application to Netlify:

[image]
[image]

The code works locally however, once deployed to Netlify it generates the above error.

Here is my Code:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
import { languageOptions, dictionaryList } from "../languages";

export const LanguageContext = createContext({
  userLanguage: "hu",
  dictionary: dictionaryList.hu,
});

export function LanguageProvider({ children }) {
  const defaultLanguage = window.localStorage.getItem("rcml-lang");
  const [userLanguage, setUserLanguage] = useState(defaultLanguage);

  const provider = {
    userLanguage,
    dictionary: dictionaryList[userLanguage],
    userLanguageChange: (selected) => {
      const newLanguage = languageOptions[selected] ? selected : "hu";
      setUserLanguage(newLanguage);
      window.localStorage.setItem("rcml-lang", newLanguage);
    },
  };

  return (
    <LanguageContext.Provider value={provider}>
      {children}
    </LanguageContext.Provider>
  );
}
export function Text({ tid }) {
  const languageContext = useContext(LanguageContext);

  return languageContext.dictionary[tid] || tid;
}
```

This is the link to the whole repository: https://github.com/fhonoria/Thermal-delikat

And finally the deploy link: https://thermaldelikat.netlify.app/

Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my site was not deployed in netlify when I use ThemeContext in my Next js app for change light mode to dark mode.

Solution: I remove the whole code in netlify. Then i was download all previus code (that was corrent) form my github. After I use it agein then my site was deploy on netlify.

I think, It's Next js 13.4 version error so you cna't solve it. After lunch 13.5 it's problem (bug) will be solved, Please read next js 13.5 documentation. in here: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-5

Thanks...